# List<> of objects, different types, sort and pull out types individually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, oop

I've got a handful of products, any, all, or none of which may be associated with a specific submission. All 7 products are subclasses of the class Product. I need to store all the products associated with a submission, and then retrieve them and their field data on my presentation layer. I've been using a `List<Product>`, and `List<object>`, but when I use the `OfType<EPL(specific subclass)>`, I throw an error saying that I can't implicitly convert `systems.generic.IEnumerable<EPL>` to type 'Product'. I've tried to cast, but to no avail.

When I use `prodlist.OfType<EPL>();` there are no errors, but when I try and store that in an instance of EPL "tempEpl", I get the aforementioned cast-related error. What gives? Code below.

```
 ProductService pserv = new ProductService();
    IList<object> prodlist = pserv.getProductById(x);

    EPL tempEpl = new EPL();

    if ((prodlist.OfType<EPL>()) != null)
    {            
       tempEpl = prodlist.OfType<EPL>();  // this throws a conversion error. 

    }
```

the Data layer

```
List<object> TempProdList = new List<object>();

    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand EplCmd = new SqlCommand(EPLQuery, conn);
    SqlDataReader EplRead = null;
    EplRead = EplCmd.ExecuteReader();

    EPL TempEpl = new EPL();
    if (EplRead.Read()) 
    {

        TempEpl.Entity1 = EplRead.GetString(0);
        TempEpl.Employees1 = EplRead.GetInt32(1);
        TempEpl.CA1 = EplRead.GetInt32(2);
        TempEpl.MI1 = EplRead.GetInt32(3);
        TempEpl.NY1 = EplRead.GetInt32(4);
        TempEpl.NJ1 = EplRead.GetInt32(5);
        TempEpl.PrimEx1 = EplRead.GetInt32(6);
        TempEpl.EplLim1 = EplRead.GetInt32(7);
        TempEpl.EplSir1 = EplRead.GetInt32(8);
        TempEpl.Premium1 = EplRead.GetInt32(9);
        TempEpl.Wage1 = EplRead.GetInt32(10);
        TempEpl.Sublim1 = EplRead.GetInt32(11);

        TempProdList.Add(TempEpl);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code makes no sense:

```
Product tempEpl = new EPL();

if ((prodlist.OfType<EPL>()) != null)
{            
   prodlist.OfType<EPL>();
}
```

- It's unclear why you're creating a new `EPL()` to start with
- `OfType()` will never return null - it returns a sequence, which may be empty
- Calling `OfType()` won't do anything useful on its own, as per the body of your `if` statement

It's important to understand that `OfType()` returns a sequence, not a single item. I suspect that's what you were missing before.

I suspect you want:

```
Product tempEpl = prodList.OfType<EPL>().FirstOrDefault();
```

This will assign a value of `null` to `tempEpl` if there are no elements of type `EPL` in `prodList`, or the first `EPL` element in the list otherwise.

(It's not clear why you're returning a `List<object>` from the data layer to start with. Why not a `List<Product>`?)

Comment: that flies. Thanks. As for the if !null, I need to determine if there is an EPL product attached to the submission. I imagine I can just run that if statement with the new tempEpl value.

Answer (score 3):

I think in DAL instead of returning a list of `Object` type you should return a list of `Product` type. If you do so then there is no need for casting it to `Product` type again.

Second thing, in the PL, instead of using `IList` just use `List`.